# Video recommendation for stock market education

Tags: investing, stocks, trading, learning

I'm just beginning my entry into stock market investing, the answers to [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5263/getting-into-the-stock-market-for-the-first-time) helped a lot.

I decided to research available videos and workshops to speed up my learning and get good expert advice, unfortunately there are literally hundreds of video packages to buy from all lengths and price ranges. Just evaluating them will take enormous amounts of time. It seems every trader who had any success has a video to sell you.

Can anyone here recommend one or more packages that will educate me on stocks, charts, options etc...

Answer (score 3):

In general I would recommend to stay away from any video from a successful trader, at least those that claim to share their secrets.

If they were that successful, why would they want company?  What they have most likely discovered is that they can make more money through videos and seminars than they can through trading.

While not a video, [GetSmarterAboutMoney](http://www.getsmarteraboutmoney.ca/Pages/default.aspx) has a good basic section on [Stock](http://www.getsmarteraboutmoney.ca/managing-your-money/investing/stocks/Pages/default.aspx) markets without being purely Canada centric (as I see from your profile you are in NY).

I know that also in our city, there are continuing education courses that often go over the basics like this, if you have a college nearby they might have something.

Cheapest of all would be to hit your local library.  The fundamentals don't change that quickly that you need the latest and greatest - those are much more likely to be get-poor-quick schemes.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Before you go filling your head with useless information as there is way too much stuff out there on the stock market. First ask yourself a few questions:

1. Why are you investing in the first place?
2. What do you realistically expect to get out of this.
3. How much time are you going to devote to this venture.

There is going to be a balance between the three... don't kid yourself.

After you answer these questions find a trading strategy to get the returns you are looking for. Remember the higher returns you expect... the more time you have to put in.

Find a trading strategy you like and that works for you. Ounce you have your strategy then find the stocks or ETF that work for that strategy.... Ignore everything else, it is designed to separate you from your money. Making money in the stock market is easy, don't let the media hype and negative people tell you any different. Find something that works for you and perfect it... stick to it.

Comment: Terrific.  How would one *find* such a strategy?  Any place to start?  Any good books?  Any sound advice to offer?  What would the typical answers to your questions lead one to deduce?  This answer feels incomplete to me.

Comment: I agree, this answer starts out well; one should consider their goals and the costs before getting into stocks. But to then say "making money in stocks is easy, by just doing whatever you like" seems to lack practical advice.